# Javascript: Sticky menu scroll glitch

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

Hello I have a shopify website and trying to implement a sticky header which changes the image position and location when some one scrolls down from header.
For that I have added the following Javascript.

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
      document.getElementById("siteheader").classList.add("sticky_header");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("siteheader").classList.remove("sticky_header");
    }
}
```

I am targeting the id of logo image and togelling the **sticky_header** class

```
<img id="siteheader" class="header__logo-image">
```

I have added the following css for moving the logo to left hand side and changing its size

```
.sticky_header {
    float: left;
    height: 45px;
    width: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

the above setup is working fine and its the desired requirement
but while scrolling to bottom the image size is fighting between the non **sticky_header** and **sticky_header** state and

Having the glitch of sudden change and not change in header size.

**And that is happening very fast on the point where .scrollTop > 20**

can some one help me to smoothen this process.

Comment: Are you changing the height of the logo? Are you using any animation/transition?

Comment: Yes height is changing as seen in css, i have tried css transition but still no help. also tried jquery animation instead of toggling class. but that is having issues of its own like the animation sometimes work and sometimes not.

Comment: Why are you doing this `window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};` and not just `window.onscroll = scrollFunction;`? I mean, it won't fix your issue, but there's no need to wrap `scrollFunction` in an anonymous function.